# Excel separate tab name in a cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with three sheets in it.

The first one is named DATE1, second one DATE2 and the third one - BASE

I need the first two cells in the BASE sheet to display DATE1 and DATE2 sheet names.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256)
```

Just point A1 to the cells of interest, i.e. DATE1!A1, etc.

Note: this only works if the workbook has been saved.

Comment: heck! it does work! thank you so much) wasted hours on figuring this out)